# RecyclerView is not visible

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a question. Why the recyclerView is invisible. I have written in the code so that the ActivityListToSerach class can retrieve an array with text to display after the data is retrieved from the MySQL database. After the data download to the RecyclerViewAdapter is finished, I send the data to display.
When I call .size () in the ActivityListToSerach class, I get 0.
Anyone have an idea how to fix it.
I am a novice programmer and I thank you immediately.

ConnectorSerach:

```
public class ConnectorSerach extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

Context context;

public ConnectorSerach (Context ctx)
{
    context = ctx;
}

public ArrayList<String> xNames = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> xPrices = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    String nameOfProduct = params[0];
    String result = "";

    try
    {
        URL url_login = new URL("http://192.168.100.9/szukajProduktu.php");
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url_login.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("name_product", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(nameOfProduct, "UTF-8");

        bufferedWriter.write(data);
        bufferedWriter.flush();

        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();

        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));

        String line = "";

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            result += line;
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        return result;
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    try
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0;i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            xNames.add(jsonObject.getString("nazwa"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityListToSerach.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

ActivityListToSerach:

```
package bjd.adrian.e_shop;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ActivityListToSerach extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_to_serach);
    this.initRecyclerView();
}

public void initRecyclerView()
{
    ConnectorSerach connectorSerach = new ConnectorSerach(this);

    if(connectorSerach.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))
    {
        ArrayList<String> sNames = connectorSerach.xNames;
        ArrayList<String> sPrices = connectorSerach.xPrices;

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, sNames, sPrices);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    }

}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
package bjd.adrian.e_shop;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";

ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> mPrices = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> pNames, ArrayList<String> pPrices)
{
    mNames = pNames;
    mPrices = pPrices;
    context = ctx;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called");
    holder.nameTV.setText(mNames.get(position));
    holder.priceTV.setText(mPrices.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return mNames.size();
}




public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView nameTV;
    TextView priceTV;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        nameTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        priceTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceTV);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your xml file??

Comment: Your AsyncTask never gets executed, to have asynctask execute, you should call execute method on the instance of the asynctask first. Try it and if further details required let us know

Comment: For better example, refer, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#asynctask

Answer (score 0):

There is a execute:

```
package bjd.adrian.e_shop;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListSerachActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_serach);
}

ConnectorSerach connectorSerach = new ConnectorSerach(this);

public void onSerach(View view) {
    EditText serachET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serachET);
    String toSerachString = serachET.getText().toString();

    connectorSerach.execute(toSerachString);

}
```

}